# Updating timestamp on column update, for multiple colums

Tags: mysql

Is the following possible:

```
table: (column1, column1_date, column2, column2_date)
```

Can I create a timestamp variable for the columns `column1_date` and `column2_date`, so when I update `column1` the timestamp on the `column1_date` is updated and when i update `column2` the timestamp on the `column2_date` is updated?

Comment: Yes, it's called a trigger.

Comment: Can you tell me how to create this?

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. First, make an attempt, and if it doesn't work, come back and tell us why it didn't work.

Comment: After reading here: http://www.mysqltutorial.org/create-the-first-trigger-in-mysql.aspx I understood a lot of things... But I still have one question: regarding the performance, is there a difference between using a trigger? Is trigger faster or slower?

Comment: Using a trigger is slower because it is called each time your action is performed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a [trigger](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/triggers.html).

Here's an example. If `column1` and/or `column2` allow `NULL` values then you'll need to change the `IF` statements to handle NULLs properly.

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS tr_b_upd_your_table $$

CREATE TRIGGER tr_b_upd_your_table BEFORE UPDATE ON your_table FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
  IF (old.column1 != new.column1)
  THEN
    SET new.column1_date = NOW();
  END IF;

  IF (old.column2 != new.column2)
  THEN
    SET new.column2_date = NOW();
  END IF;

END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Thanks! I only need to use this once, correct? Also, is this faster or slower vs updating the columns using the UPDATE?

Comment: So, i won't use them... Thanks for the info!